# Jekyll /gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:171:in `load': end of file reached (EOFError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, yaml, jekyll, bundle

when I try run `jekyll serve --trace` this error message appears:

```
Configuration file: /Users/John/Projects/contrast/_config.yml
Traceback (most recent call last):
    19: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    18: from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `process_with_graceful_fail'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `each'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:89:in `block in process_with_graceful_fail'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `process'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:30:in `new'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:33:in `initialize'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:113:in `reset'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:41:in `clear_if_config_changed'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:86:in `[]'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:171:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/jekyll-4.0.0/lib/jekyll/cache.rb:171:in `load': end of file reached (EOFError)
```

This is my important parts of my `_confing.yml` file:

```
title: "Blog Title"
author: "Blog Author"
permalink: /:title/
lang: "en"
date_format: "%B %d, %Y"

plugins:
 - jekyll-feed
```

How can I solve this so jekyll can run normally ? Thank you for any help.

Comment: I have copied provided `_config.yml` and it worked with jekyll 4.0.0. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Try deleting the entire `.jekyll-cache` folder. Then build your site multiple times to see if the issue recurs.

Comment: @DracoAter I can provide more information. Just tell me what you need. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

I run out of disk space during site generation and it made some corrupted files.

### Solution

Solution to this problem was to delete `_site` and `.jekyll-cache` and directories and run `jekyll serve --trace` again. (Yes you have to delete both of them). Obviously I made more disk space to prevent this error.